# How to update joystick state

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I want to update the joystick state every time I press a button on it or move the axis of the joystick. I have this code already:

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput

 Dim js As Device = Nothing

 For Each DI As DeviceInstance In Manager.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, _
     EnumDevicesFlags.AttachedOnly)

     js = New Device(DI.InstanceGuid)
     Exit For
 Next

 If js Is Nothing Then
     Throw New Exception("No joystick found")
 End If

 Dim wih As New System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Me)
 js.SetCooperativeLevel(wih.Handle, CooperativeLevelFlags.NonExclusive Or _
     CooperativeLevelFlags.Background)
 js.Acquire()

 Dim state As JoystickState = js.CurrentJoystickState
```

The last line gets the state of the joystick. I have seen that a timer is used and every time it ticks the state is refreshed, but it seems not efficient because if I don't push any button the state is refreshed anyway. So how would I refresh the state only when needed?

Comment: Does it matter? I assume it's order of 50 or 100 times a second - probably to match the frame rate? - and you're not attaching expensive operations to the update, so what's the issue? It could well be that the OS doesn't have a notify-of-joystick-changes mechanism so code somewhere is forced to poll.

Comment: @Rup If I use a dispatcher timer, how big should the time span be?

Comment: ... oh, I see - my misunderstanding, sorry. I read that as 'there is a timer provided by DX and I want a better solution' not 'I've seen other people use timers'. If you really do need to poll - if there's no 'register event notificaiton' for DirectInput devices - then you might as well just do it at the frequency your game processes input, which will either be on vsync or in your background world-update thread I guess?

Comment: I support your question. I am looking for an efficient solution. I found this link that might help but didn't help me: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/171374/Creating-A-Joystick-Event

Answer (score 0):

I found some C# code on how to update the state of the joystick only when the joystick state has changed. I see you've got:

```
Dim state As JoystickState = js.CurrentJoystickState
```

Maybe try just adding in something like the example below: "THIS IS C#"

```
            //Capture Position.
            info += "X:" + state.X + " ";
            info += "Y:" + state.Y + " ";
            info += "Z:" + state.Z + " ";

            //Capture Buttons.
            byte[] buttons = state.GetButtons();
            for(int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
            {
                if(buttons[i] != 0)
                {
                    info += "Button:" + i + " ";
                }
            }
```

Here's the whole snippet I found located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dx_DirectInput_capturing_device_objects

```
private void UpdateJoystick()
    {
        string info = "Joystick: ";

        //Get Mouse State.
        JoystickState state = joystick.CurrentJoystickState;

        //Capture Position.
        info += "X:" + state.X + " ";
        info += "Y:" + state.Y + " ";
        info += "Z:" + state.Z + " ";

        //Capture Buttons.
        byte[] buttons = state.GetButtons();
        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            if(buttons[i] != 0)
            {
                info += "Button:" + i + " ";
            }
        }

        lbJoystick.Text = info;
    }
```

Comment: But this looks like it's just reading the current state of the joystick, and so needs be called regularly to poll joystick state, rather than detecting or being notified when the joystick state has changed?

Comment: I think someone has already said this but why wouldn't a timer tick be sufficient? just because it's not an actual timer in DirectX?